# How can I check to see if an Excel file is closed before uploading it Excel Online via a WebAPI endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-web-api

I have an endpoint that is uploading an excel file and is submitting it to excel online for a data conversion.

I would like to check to make sure the file is not open before submitting it.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> submitfile()
    {
        var dataStream = new MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider();

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(dataStream);

        DataTable data;


        if (!dataStream.FileData.Any())
        {
            return BadRequest("No file sent.");
        }

        try
        {
            data = await CreateDataTableFromExcelFileDataNew(dataStream);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("There was an issue with the spreadsheet or API.  " + ex.Message);
        }    

 //The data is format and processed correctly.  This part has been removed sense it is working correctly.  
 return Ok();

    }
```

I tried to see if there was a method/property inside of MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider() that would check to see if the file was closed before uploading it and I didn't see a way.

Is there another way I should check to see if the file is closed?

Comment: So I assume this situation is part of a bigger system.  Just guessing here, but perhaps you just created the file using Excel via Automation.  Getting Excel to cleanly close under automation is often tricky.  Minor things can make it stay open.  If my assumption is correct, you need to look at your automation code, not so much the submit code.  For testing purposes, after you've created the file, see if the copy of Excel that created the file goes away.  I wouldn't go so far as to say it is a "notorious" Excel problem, but it is a common problem.

Comment: It is part of a large intranet application.  The problem is some users aren't saving their changes in the excel file before uploading.

Comment: So I just saw your "uploading" comment . . . so automation isn't exactly the issue.  So perhaps you problem is more like the upload is still in progress?  This kind of thing probably generates a very specific exception (or two).  Catch that one exception separately and when you get it, requeue and retry the request at a later time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've not been able to duplicate the issue.  Do you what the exceptions would be?

Comment: Print the exceptions in a log and look . . .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "uploading to Excel Online". Do you mean OneDrive? SharePoint? Excel Online is only a data editing tool, it can't store files in it like your question wording suggestions.

Comment: Anyway, you need to do this at the desktop application level first. Don't even activate the ASP.NET functionality that uses the API until you've checked via VBA or PowerShell or something that the file is closed.